# Spacing between minitoc and next section

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, minitoc

Please, how can I delete space between minitoc and the introduction?

```
\chapter{chapter 1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\minitoc
\label{CHAPTER1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: I'd put the `\label` before `\minitoc` (just for being on the safe side). Why are you doing `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}`?

Comment: to reduce spacing between lines in the minitoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\vspace` to add or delete vertical space before or after `\minitoc`. For example:

```
\vspace{-8ex}
\minitoc
\vspace{-2ex}
```

You can also define this group of commands as new command (`\miniminitoc`, for instance) in the preample:

```
\newcommand{\miniminitoc}{
\vspace{-11ex}
\minitoc
\vspace{-5ex}}
```

And then simply change `\minitoc` by `\miniminitoc`  in all chapters. This is convenient to maintain a clean code in the body but also for subsequent adjustments (since only is needed to make changes in the preamble to adjust all the indexs)